# SQL QUery, Insert, Union and Join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I get an "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists".

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.FactInternetSales (
    ProductKey
    ,CustomerKey
    ,DateKey
    ,OrderQuantity
    ,UnitPrice
    ,UnitPriceDiscount
    ,TaxAmt
    ,Freight
    )
SELECT ProductKey
FROM dbo.dimProduct

UNION ALL

SELECT CustomerKey
FROM dbo.dimCustomer

UNION ALL

SELECT DateKey
FROM dbo.dimDate

UNION ALL

SELECT D.OrderQty
    ,D.UnitPrice
    ,D.UnitPriceDiscount
    ,H.TaxAmt
    ,H.Freight
FROM AdventureWorksLT2008.SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail AS D
FULL JOIN AdventureWorksLT2008.SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader H ON D.SalesOrderID = H.SalesOrderID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all..Final query in union all doesnt have columns as others..You can try below which works ,since you dont have common columns to join in your code

You may want to try this

```
;With cte
as
(
Select ProductKey From dbo.dimProduct
UNION All
Select CustomerKey From dbo.dimCustomer 
UNION All
Select DateKey From dbo.dimDate )
,cte1 as
(
Select D.OrderQty,
    D.UnitPrice,
    D.UnitPriceDiscount,
    H.TaxAmt,
    H.Freight   
From        AdventureWorksLT2008.SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail As D
FULL JOIN   AdventureWorksLT2008.SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader H
ON D.SalesOrderID = H.SalesOrderID
)
select cte.*,cte1.*
from cte,cte1
```

Comment: i dont get it, your code shows incorrect syntax. i did understand the error i got but could not solve the problem while trying to insert it into the table

Comment: See updated,this works .you also can use join too if they have same columns

Comment: thank you i was able to get what i wanted from the concept you gave. I removed union all and used WITH  cte1, cte2, cte3, cte4 to get Productkey, CustomerKey, DateKey in different columns

Answer (score 0):

When i try to insert in the following way i get an error The instance of the SQL Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK resource at this time. Rerun your statement when there are fewer active users. Ask the database administrator to check the lock and memory configuration for this instance, or to check for long-running transactions.

```
    WITH cte1
AS (
    SELECT ProductKey
    FROM dbo.dimProduct
    )
    ,cte2
AS (
    SELECT CustomerKey
    FROM dbo.dimCustomer
    )
    ,cte3
AS (
    SELECT DateKey
    FROM dbo.dimDate
    )
    ,cte4
AS (
    SELECT D.OrderQty
        ,D.UnitPrice
        ,D.UnitPriceDiscount
        ,H.TaxAmt
        ,H.Freight
    FROM AdventureWorksLT2008.SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail AS D
    FULL JOIN AdventureWorksLT2008.SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader H ON D.SalesOrderID = H.SalesOrderID
    )
INSERT INTO dbo.FactInternetSales (
    ProductKey
    ,CustomerKey
    ,DateKey
    ,OrderQuantity
    ,UnitPrice
    ,UnitPriceDiscount
    ,TaxAmt
    ,Freight
    )
SELECT cte1.*
    ,cte2.*
    ,cte3.*
    ,cte4.*
FROM cte1
    ,cte2
    ,cte3
    ,cte4
```